# Mod_wsgi + Python 2.7.3 Segmentation Fault (11)

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I've compiled on a RHEL5 the Python 2.7.3 + mod_wsgi 3.4.

Running my scripts, I've seen that sometimes they work but most of the time I see a blank page. I've checked the error log and I've seen this:

```
[Tue Dec 04 11:37:40 2012] [notice] child pid 21822 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I've used the gdb on Apache CoreDump file to trace the error and I can see this:

```
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00002ab6a98b3c32 in CThunkObject_dealloc (_self=<value optimized out>) at /backup/moving/python/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:24
24      Py_XDECREF(self->restype);
```

My mod_wsgi.so files is linked to those libraries:

```
 ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00002b7051fb8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b7052385000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b70525a0000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b70527a5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b70529a8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b7052c2b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003191400000)
```

This error does not happen anytime but randomly. Do you have any clue on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try Google at all? The top hit for 'mod_wsgi _ctypes' looks related. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=645193

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IssuesWithExpatLibrary seems like it might be your issue.